# How to check whether to show the login form or [logged in] user details?

Tags: php

I want to show two different elements depending on whether a user has logged in or not. If they are not logged in I will show one element with `include "./navn.PHP";`, and if they are `include "./navl.PHP";`

I have the following code:

```php
require_once("connection.php");
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['user_login'];

$select_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id = :uid");
$select_stmt->execute(array(':uid' => $id));
$row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (empty($row["username"]))  {
    include "./navn.php";
} else {
    include "./navl.php";
}
```

But my solution does not seem to work -- I log in and it shows the register and login buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need to be logged to have the $_SESSION['user_login']

just use

```
if(!$_SESSION['user_login']){
   include "./navn.php";
}else{
   include "./navl.php";
}
```

or create a function

```
function isLogged($id){
   //using mysqli procedure
   global $db;
   $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE id = $id");
   $data = $query->fetch_assoc();
   if(!$data["username"]){
      return 0;
   }else{
      return 1;
   }

}

if(isLogged($_SESSION['user_login']) == 0){
   include "./navn.php";
}else{
   include "./navl.php";
}
```